# Difference between this two generic view

Tags: python, django

1. from django.views.generic import CreateView

2.from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

Whats the difference between them ?

Comment: There is no difference. `from django.views.generic import CreateView` is importing the class from the `__init__` file, which is importing `CreateView` from `edit.py`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module to get the file from where the module is imported.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfile(django.views.generic.edit.CreateView)
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py'
```

and

```
>>> inspect.getfile(django.views.generic.CreateView)
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py'
```

Effectively, they're the same. The second import will import the class from `__init__.py` which will then proceed to import `CreateView` from `edit.py`.

If you view the contents of `__init__.py`, it'll specify an import statement there:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import (
    CreateView, DeleteView, FormView, UpdateView,
)
```

You can see that importing the module through `__init__` will import `CreateView`.